# How to control 0-5V in 5 steps? (1V, 2V, 3V, 4V and 5V)

Tags: voltage-divider

I want to change a 10k potentiometer that is connected as a voltage divider to a 5V supply.

So, instead of a potentiometer, I need a way to divide that 5V supply into 5V steps (1V, 2V, 3V, 4V and 5V) and to be as esthetically as possible. What would you use?

Comment: A 5 position rotary switch with a nice knob would be aesthetic for me. What's the required compliance current?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes!

Comment: @periblepsis very small current

Comment: @tibi10 ‘very small’ is subjective, some people might say milliamps is very small, others might say picoamps. Give us a number. Also what kind of accuracy do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rotary switch + resistor ladder will work. A rotary switch being a selector switch where only one position at a time is selected, mechanically. So note that the switches in the below schematic is actually one single component, in the rotary switch case.

Resistor values don't really matter much as long as they are all the same. 1k gives a robust design, 10k gives low current consumption etc. The switch might have a minimum current specified, depending on material.

[image]

Live in the Falstad simulator: https://tinyurl.com/2xo7hfct

Answer (score 0):

If the unspoken requirements were compatible with this proposed solution, I would at least consider an MCU using PWM and a low-pass filter.

Whether you use switches, an encoder, membrane keys, and LEDs or a display of some kind for the HMI is another question.